# Setting a UIImageView with ALAsset

Tags: iphone, alasset

I have a UIImageView and would like to set it to the contents of an ALAsset.

How is the ALAssets contents used to set a UIImage?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Asset is ALAsset by the way.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail] scale:1.0 orientation:[[asset defaultRepresentation] orientation]]

UIImageView *image_view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]
```

Comment: ALAsset doesn't respond to orientation, you would have to do: [[result valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyOrientation"] intValue] and it still returns a ALAssetOrientation, not UIImageOrientation, which I'm not sure if they share values. After setting that UIImage to a UIImageView, nothing is displayed...

Comment: ALAssetRepresentation (which is what is returned by `-defaultRepresentation`) responds to `-orientation`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [self defaultRepresentation];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullScreenImage]];
```

Comment: i'm getting memory warning on iPhone 6 when picking 6 photos at once

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Clayton and Aaron Brager, the key is imageWithCGImage method of UIImage class.

There are a two ways to get image content:

- asset.thumbnail or asset.aspectThumbnail
- via a presentation of the asset

  - there are default presentation and presentation for UTI
  - CGImage prepared

    - CGImageWithOptions, fullResolutionImage, fullScreenImage
  - raw data

    - getBytes:fromOffset:length:error:
    - (if you want to keep EXIF etc, use imageWithData instead of imageWithCGImage)

You may refer http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/ALAssetRepresentation for more details.